# Complexity classes examples

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

I wanted to know if my answers are indeed correct for the following statements:

3(n^3) + 5(n^2) + 25n + 10 = BigOmega(n^3) -> T
->Grows at a rate equals or slower

3(n^3) + 5(n^2) + 25n + 10 = Theta(n^3) -> T
-Grows at a rate exactly equals

3(n^3) + 5(n^2) + 25n + 10 = BigO(n^3) -> T
-Grows at a rate equals or faster

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formal definitions of `O` notations are:

> f(n) = O(g(n)) means that there exists some constant c and n0 that
>   f(n) <= c*g(n) for n >= n0.
>
> f(n) = Ω(g(n)) means that there exists some constant c and n0 that
>   f(n) >= c*g(n) for n >= n0.
>
> f(n) = Θ(g(n)) means that there exists some constants c1 and c2 and n0
>   that f(n) >= c1*g(n) and f(n) <= c2*g(n) for n >= n0.

Proof for O:

```
3(n^3) + 5(n^2) + 25n + 10 < 3*n^3 + n^3 + n^3 = 5*n^3
```

You can see that for `n >= 10` this formula is true.
So there exists `c = 5` and `n0 = 10`, thus it is `O(n^3)`.

Proof for Ω:

```
3(n^3) + 5(n^2) + 25n + 10 > 3*n^3
```

So `c = 3` and `n0 = 1`, thus it is `Ω(n^3)`.

Because both `O` and `Ω` apply then the 3rd statement for `Θ` is also true.

Comment: Perfect! I got down those concepts so I was just trying to keep it simple. Thank you for reassuring my answers though! I appreciate it!